# Control focus styling

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, styles

[image]

in above image you would notice that, doted rectangle indicating ComboBox is focused
But the problem is it exceeding the text area of ComboBox... how do I align it with text area **WPF Style**?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your ControlTemplate it's difficult to give the best way to change it.

One slightly hackish way to do it is set Focusable on the ComboBox to False and then set Focusable on the TextBlock (or Label) to True. This should make it so the TextBlock gets focus whenever the ComboBox should.

My best guess though is that you have some weird margins going on, the real way to fix it would be to straighten those out.